# Inserting a key value pair after a certain key value in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to insert a key value pair at the end of an array of values retrieved from a database query. I tried `array_splice` but that wasn't doing exactly what I wanted, so I'm trying `array_push` but it's not adding it to the array.

Here is my code:

```
public function listFriendsStatus()
{
    // get the friend statuses of the logged in user
    $connection = $this->sql->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection();

    $query = $connection->execute("SELECT status.id, status, time_status, members.username FROM status
        INNER JOIN friends ON friends.friend_id = status.id 
        INNER JOIN members ON members.id = status.id
        WHERE friends.user_id = " . $this->getUserId()['id']);

    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        $status_holder = array();

        foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
            $status_holder[$key] = $value;

            $status_dir = '/images/profile/' . $status_holder[$key]['username'] . '/status/' . $status_holder[$key]['time_status'] . '/';

            $real_dir = getcwd() . '/public/' . $status_dir;

            if (is_dir($real_dir)) {
                $images = array_diff(scandir($real_dir, 1), array('.', '..'));
                array_push($status_holder, array('images' => $images));
            } else {
                array_push($status_holder, array('images' => ''));
            }
        }

        return $status_holder;
    } else {
        throw new FeedException("No friend statuses were found.");
    }
}
```

For a better explanation, here is a `var_export` of my array

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'status' => 'this is jimmy, test', 'time_status' => '0', 'username' => 'jimmy', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'status' => 'this is jimmy 2, test', 'time_status' => '0', 'username' => 'timmy', ), 2 => array ( 'images' => '', ), )
```

What I am trying to do is insert after each `["username"]` key and value, the images key and value from the images array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

(I can try and make the question clearer if need be)

update

```
$status_holder[$key]['images'] = $images;
```

did what I need.

Comment: You should turn on error display: What you are doing is not possible. And you misunderstand what `end()` does; it returns the last element of the array.

Comment: you can't insert a key value pair after a certain key value pair?

Comment: You can, but I was referring to your code: The first parameter of `array_push()` is passed by reference and you cannot add another element to the `end()` function. Displaying errors or checking your error log will show that right away.

Comment: Just add the key value pair into the array, don't worry about it's location.

Comment: *For a better explanation* don't use `var_dump()`. Use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

Comment: @NigelRen but would it add the key value to the array corresponding to each username key value

Comment: @jeroen I updated my question

Comment: To add the array in the correct place, all you need is `$status_holder[$key]['images'] = $images;`

Comment: yeah I just figured that out, thanks @jeroen

Comment: Read about [accessing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) and [creating/modifying array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your foreach is retrieving a row at a time, then add the image into this data and then build your other array...

```
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    $status_dir = '/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/' . $value['time_status'] . '/';

    $real_dir = getcwd() . '/public/' . $status_dir;

    if (is_dir($real_dir)) {
        $images = array_diff(scandir($real_dir, 1), array('.', '..'));
        $value['images'] = $images;
    } else {
        $value['images'] = '';
    }
    $status_holder[$key] = $value;
}
```